# Large, unexplained gap in Unity launcher

Tags: 14.04, unity

As you can tell from the screenshot, there is a large gap in my Unity launcher for no reason. I was locking and unlocking some things from my Unity launcher, and it just happened. I don't know why. Is this a bug? How do I fix this?

[image: Screenshot of Unity launcher]

Comment: To anyone else who is having this problem, it fixes itself after a reboot, as the bug report mentioned by Toroidal says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a known bug, a bug report has even been filed on it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1400402